# Reuse custom exception information

Tags: java, exception

I wonder if it is a good practice to reuse thrown exceptions information for another sake than to just provide information about an error.

For example :

```
public class ProcessException extends Exception {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7718828512143293558L;

    private final ErrorReport errorReport;

    public ProcessException(ErrorReport report) {
        super();
        this.errorReport = report;
    }

    public ProcessException(String message, Throwable cause, ErrorReport code) {
        super(message, cause);
        this.errorReport = errorReport;
    }

    public ProcessException(String message, ErrorReport report) {
        super(message);
        this.errorReport = report;
    }

    public ProcessException(Throwable cause, ErrorReport report) {
        super(cause);
        this.errorReport = report;
    }

    public ErrorReport getErrorReport() {
        return this.errorReport;
    }
}
```

I want for example to throw a `ProcessException` and then reuse the `ErrorReport` for displaying in my GUI what went wrong during the processing.

Please feel free to ask me more details if my purpose isn't clear

Comment: It is indeed good practice.  If you’re worried about using the same ErrorReport object in multiple places, the same rules apply to it as with any shared object, starting with:  don’t modify it.

Comment: Never seen it before, except for nested exceptions (like when you see "caused by SomeOtherException"). At first sight I'd be hesitant to implement it this way. Depends on what information is in the ErrorReport.